# postgresql - query with not equal doesn't work

Tags: postgresql

this is dumb question but still, I'm trying to write a not equal where clause with postgresql the documentation show that the sign is `<>` or `!=` both always return 0 results
the where is on an integer field.

```
select userid from users where usertype <> 2;
select userid from users where usertype != 2;
```

the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    UserID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR (20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    UserType INTEGER NULL
    );
```

**Note:** the following workaround worka and return results

```
select userid from users where usertype < 2 or usertype > 2;
```

I was just wondering if anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Could you copy and paste your query here ?

Comment: Maybe you are comparing NULL "values" ? (in line 3)

Comment: Post your query here.

Comment: @Abincepto, Rahul I've edited my question to include the query

Comment: That means there is no record other than `usertype = 2`

Comment: Can you provide ddl `create table (...);` and `insert` statements so we know the structure of the data and what data is inserted?

Comment: What is the result of SELECT usertype, COUNT(1) as nb FROM users GROUP BY usertype ? Do you have a line with usertype different than 2 ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is absolutely no difference between `<>` and `!=` (with `<>` being what the SQL standard defined for "not equals")

Comment: You should post what version of PostgreSQL you are using also.  Not that it should really make a difference here.  Also, I would also suggest that you post your DDL for the table.

Comment: What would `SELECT usertype, usertype != 2 from users` return? Is the result of the expression evaluation correct?

Comment: @zerkms it return nothing for the emapty/null usertype and false for those with 2

Comment: @liv a: what means "nothing"? There is no such data type in postgresql.

Comment: @zerkms 
   
          | 
          | 
        2 | f